# HTML Anchor href and onclick not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have my anchor, onclick and href as below:

```
 <a href="/SSRS?reportid=@rpt.ReportId" title="Click to run this report" class="ssrsReportLink" role="button">@rpt.ReportDescription</a>

 $('.ssrsReportLink').on('click', function () {
        var itemClicked = $(this).text();
        Log.LogAct({ TypeId: 56, AreaId: 57, objectReference: itemClicked });
    });
```

In Firefox this onclick gets called but it doesn't completes the whole call of logging action and redirects to the action method. Tried several ways but no luck so far. Any help is greatly appreciated. Above code working fine in IE and Chrome!!

Comment: what `Log.LogAct()` returns? Promise?

Comment: LogAct is a method which insert the entry into the database. It always fails and link redirects controls to action method. If i preventdefault, it writes a record to database but then it doesn't redirect to action method. What can i do ?

Comment: use `preventDefault` method